# Java generic merge

Tags: java, generics

I wrote a merge function that merges two sorted lists into a single sorted list. The followings are the scenario for the code.

1. Merging the lists [2, 4, 6], [3, 5, 6, 7] produces [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7].
2. Merging the lists [“Alice”, “Tom”], [“Bob”, “Richard”] produces [“Alice”, “Bob”, “Richard”, “Tom”].
3. Merging the lists [2.3, 4.5], [2,5] produces [2, 2.3, 4.5, 5].
4. Merging the lists [“A”, “XYZ”, “AXTU”] and [2, 4, 6] (where the first list is sorted by word length, and in the merge operation, if a string length in the first list is the same as a number in the second list, the string comes first) produces [“A”, 2, “XYZ”, “AXTU”, 4, 6];

   ```
    public static void testCombine() {
       ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainList = new ArrayList<>();
       ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Alice", "Tom"));
       ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Bob", "Richard"));
       mainList.add(list1);
       mainList.add(list2);
       System.out.println(combine(mainList.stream()));
   }

   private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> ArrayList<T> combine(Stream<ArrayList<T>> stream) {
       return stream.reduce((x, y) -> {
           x.addAll(y);
           Collections.sort(x);
           return x;
       }).get();
   }
   ```

*But, I was not getting the result for 3 and 4 types. I have to Implement the most general possible merge function, assuming that input lists are in sorted order (according to a natural or a specified ordering)*

Comment: Provide a custom `Comparator` to `Collections.sort()` for #4

Comment: Don't force your users to make a stream when all they want is to merge two lists. Your combine method should have the signature `static <T extends Comparable<T>, U extends Comparable<U>> List<Object> combine(List<T> tList, List<U> uList)`. Use a custom comparator when T and U are String and Integer.

Comment: Also, the whole point of merging _sorted_ lists is that you shouldn't have to sort them again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this similar to what you want?  There may be a simpler method to do this using `Stream` and it is better to use `List<String>` as opposed to `ArrayList<String>` whenever possible, for example `List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>`

```
public static void testCombine() {
    List<String> stringList1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "AB", "XYZ", "AXTU"));
    List<Integer> integerList2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6));
    System.out.println(Main.combine(stringList1, integerList2, new MergeTwoTypes<String, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Function<? super Integer, ? extends String> map() {
            return (x)->Integer.toString(x);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isVal2Larger(String val, Integer val2) {
            return val.length()>val2;
        }
    }));
    List<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2.3, 4.5));
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 5));
    System.out.println(Main.combine(list1, list2, new MergeTwoTypes<Double, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Function<? super Integer, ? extends Double> map() {
            return ((Integer x) -> new Double(x));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isVal2Larger(Double val, Integer val2) {
            return val>val2;
        }
    }));
}

private static <T, U> List<T> combine(List<T> vals1, List<U> vals2, MergeTwoTypes<T, U> mergeTwoTypes) {
    List<T> list=new ArrayList<>();
    int vals2Index=0;
    for(T val:vals1) {
        for(; vals2Index<vals2.size(); vals2Index++) {
            U val2=vals2.get(vals2Index);
            if(mergeTwoTypes.isVal2Larger(val, val2)) {
                list.add(mergeTwoTypes.map().apply(val2));
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        list.add(val);
    }
    for(; vals2Index<vals2.size(); vals2Index++) {
        U val2=vals2.get(vals2Index);
        list.add(mergeTwoTypes.map().apply(val2));
    }
    return list;
}

private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> combine(List<T> vals1, List<T> vals2) {
    List<T> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.addAll(vals1);
    list.addAll(vals2);
    Collections.sort(list);
    return list;
}

interface MergeTwoTypes<T,U> {
    boolean isVal2Larger(T val, U val2);
    Function<? super U, ? extends T> map();
}
```