# Passing user defined method for merging behaviour in HashMap Java8

Tags: java, merge, java-8, hashmap

I want to provide the user defined method to merge the map in java 8? The method you create should accept two maps and “merging” behavior.

```
 public <T> Map<? super T, ? super T> mergeMaps( Map<? super T, ? super 
 T> map1, Map<? super T, ? super T> map2 ) {
 // merging code here
 }
```

but I want something like this

```
public <T> Map<? super T, ? super T> mergeMaps( Map<? super T, ? super T> 
map1, Map<? super T, ? super T> map2 , MergeTwoMaps<T, U> mergeTwoMaps) 
{
    // merging code here
}
```

Something like this. [Java generic merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255206/java-generic-merge/40257232#40257232)

```
 Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
 Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
 map1.put(“key1”, 20);
 map1.put(“key2”, 30);
 map2.put(“key3”, 40);
 map2.put(“key1”, 50);

mergeMaps(map1,map2,mergeBehaviour)
Output should be
map.get("key1")--> 70

Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
 Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
 map1.put(“key1”, "Hello");
 map1.put(“key2”, "Hi");
 map2.put(“key3”, "Ok");
 map2.put(“key1”, "world");
 mergeMaps(map1,map2,mergeBehaviour)

 Output should be
 map.get("key1")--> Helloworld
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking at as an operation when you say merge the map(entries)? In the current scenario, it looks like the sum of values, is that it? Or to rephrase the question, what is `MergeTwoTypes` expected to be?

Comment: Hi naman, I am looking writing a generic method which accepts two map instances. 
mergeMaps(map1<Integer,String>,map2<Integer,String>, mergingBehaviour("ConcatString")
mergeMaps(map1<Integer,Integer>,map2<Integer,Integer>, mergingBehaviour("AddIntegers")
if the key is same in both the maps

Answer (score 6):

You should rethink your desired method signature. To cite [the guidelines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html):

> Using a wildcard as a return type should be avoided because it forces programmers using the code to deal with wildcards.

In other words, having wildcards in the return types forces the caller to spread wildcards into every code using the returned result.

The method should rather look like:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> mergeMaps(
    Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map1, Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map2,
    BinaryOperator<V> mergeFunction) {

    Map<K, V> result = new HashMap<>(map1);
    map2.forEach((k,v) -> result.merge(k, v, mergeFunction));
    return result;
}
```

It allows the caller to pick arbitrary key and value types, as long as the input argument are compatible, which is always the case if the input maps’ key and value types are the same as the output map’s or subtypes of it. Of course, this signature also allows the use case where key and value types are the same, but it does not require it.

The implementation of the merge operation itself is trivial.

You can raise the method’s flexibility even more by using

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> mergeMaps(
    Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map1, Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map2,
    BiFunction<? super V, ? super V, ? extends V> mergeFunction) {

    Map<K, V> result = new HashMap<>(map1);
    map2.forEach((k,v) -> result.merge(k, v, mergeFunction));
    return result;
}
```

though this is rarely needed, because it’s unnecessary when passing method references or lambda expressions. This only helps when reusing already existing `BiFunction` instances.